# Keras RBF (radial basis functions) layer for image classification is not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I want to build an image classifier using an RBF layer, Keras, and the fashionMNIST dataset. The model compiles correctly, the only issue I have is that the model is not learning anything, basically classifies any image to some label it comes up with ending up with 10% accuracy all the time (please note that the fashionMNIST is a balanced dataset of 10 classes).

Here is the implementation

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform, Initializer, Constant
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

class InitCentersRandom(Initializer):
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X

    def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
        assert shape[1] == self.X.shape[1]
        idx = np.random.randint(self.X.shape[0], size=shape[0])
        return self.X[idx, :]

class RBFLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, initializer=None, betas=1.0, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.init_betas = betas
        if not initializer:
            self.initializer = RandomUniform(0.0, 1.0)
        else:
            self.initializer = initializer
        super(RBFLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.centers = self.add_weight(name='centers',
                                      shape=(self.output_dim, input_shape[1]),
                                      initializer=self.initializer,
                                      trainable=True)
        self.betas = self.add_weight(name='betas',
                                    shape=(self.output_dim,),
                                    initializer=Constant(value=self.init_betas),
                                    trainable=True)
        super(RBFLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        C = K.expand_dims(self.centers)
        H = K.transpose(C - K.transpose(x))
        return K.exp(-self.betas * K.sum(H**2, axis=1))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'output_dim': self.output_dim
        }
        base_config = super(RBFLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

# Load and preprocess the data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
X = X.reshape((len(X), -1))
y = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)

# Create the RBFLayer model
rbflayer = RBFLayer(20,
                initializer=InitCentersRandom(X),
                betas=2.0,
                input_shape=X.shape[1:])
model = Sequential()
model.add(rbflayer)
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

# Compile and train the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=2, verbose=True)
```

And for testing the model I am using:

```
# Assuming you have a trained model 'model' and test data 'x_test' and 'y_test'

# Preprocess the test data
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.0
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), -1))
y_test_categorical = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)

# Evaluate the model on the test data
loss = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test_categorical, verbose=0)

# Make predictions on the test data
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

# Calculate accuracy
correct_predictions = np.sum(y_pred_classes == y_test)
total_samples = len(y_test)
accuracy = correct_predictions / total_samples

print(f'Test Loss: {loss:.4f}')
print(f'Test Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%')
```

I attempted different hyperparams, RBF kernals, initial weights, etc, but the model always ends up giving ~10% accuracy.

Comment: Why are you using the mean_squared_error as loss function?

Comment: When you are changing something important in response to a comment (like the one by @stateMachine here, which seems to have led you to change the loss and the metric), please leave a comment explaining.